# A Program that sits in the Notification Area

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, c++-cli

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

If I build a program, how can I get it to hide in the notifications area(windows 7, cant remember what it's called in XP or Vista) when I minimize it? Like say a Torrent program, or a AntiVirus program.

Also I'd like to know, how can I hide it from the notifications area and bring it up when it a hotkey command is entered?

Any clues on any of these two problems I'm having for an a program I am doing would be great.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If your C++/CLI program works with Windows Forms, you can use NotifyIcon component:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx